# Where does this session come from?

Tags: php, session

I have a header.html which start with session_start();.
Then the following code, $_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id] is not set, but suddenly came out. 
Q1. Can you start session in this way?
Q2. How come you can increment quantity of purchase with $_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id]++?
It seems to me incrementing id number.

```
<?php # Script 5.7 - cart.php

/* 
 *  This is the shopping cart page.
 *  This page has two modes:
 *  - add a product to the cart
 *  - update the cart
 *  The page shows the cart as a form for updating quantities.
 */

// Require the configuration file before any PHP code:
require_once ('./includes/config.inc.php');

// Include the header file:
$page_title = 'Shopping Cart';
include_once ('./includes/header.html');

echo '<h1>View Your Shopping Cart</h1>';

// This page will either add to or update the 
// shopping cart, based upon the value of $_REQUEST['do'];
if (isset($_REQUEST['do']) && ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'add') ) { // Add new item.

    if (isset($_GET['sw_id'])) { // Check for a product ID.

        // Typecast to an integer:
        $sw_id = (int) $_GET['sw_id'];

        // If it's a positive integer,
        // get the item information:
        if ($sw_id > 0) {

            // Define and execute the query:
            $q = "SELECT name, color, size FROM general_widgets LEFT JOIN specific_widgets USING (gw_id) LEFT JOIN colors USING (color_id) LEFT JOIN sizes USING (size_id) WHERE sw_id=$sw_id";
            $r = mysqli_query($dbc, $q);

            if (mysqli_num_rows($r) == 1) {

                // Get the information:
    list ($name, $color, $size) = mysqli_fetch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM);

                // If the cart already contains 
                // one of these widgets, increment the quantity:
                if (isset($_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id])) {

                    $_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id]++;

                    // Display a message:
    echo "<p>Another copy of '$name' in color $color, size $size has been added to your shopping cart.</p>\n";

                } else { // New to the cart.

                    // Add to the cart.
                    $_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id] = 1;

                    // Display a message:
                    echo "<p>The widget '$name' in color $color, size $size has been added to your shopping cart.</p>\n";

                }

            } // End of mysqli_num_rows() IF.

        } // End of ($sw_id > 0) IF.

    } // End of isset($_GET['sw_id']) IF.

} elseif (isset($_REQUEST['do']) && ($_REQUEST['do'] == 'update')) {

    // Change any quantities...
    // $k is the product ID.
    // $v is the new quantity.
    foreach ($_POST['qty'] as $k => $v) {

        // Must be integers!
        $pid = (int) $k;
        $qty = (int) $v;

        if ($qty == 0) { // Delete item.    
            unset ($_SESSION['cart'][$pid]);            
        } elseif ($qty > 0) { // Change quantity.       
            $_SESSION['cart'][$pid] = $qty;         
        }

    } // End of FOREACH.

    // Print a message.
    echo '<p>Your shopping cart has been updated.</p>';

} // End of $_REQUEST IF-ELSE.

// Show the shopping cart if it's not empty:
if (isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])) {

    // Retrieve all of the information for the products in the cart:
    $q = "SELECT sw_id, name, color, size, default_price, price FROM general_widgets LEFT JOIN specific_widgets USING (gw_id) LEFT JOIN colors USING (color_id) LEFT JOIN sizes USING (size_id) WHERE sw_id IN (";

    // Add each product ID.
    foreach ($_SESSION['cart'] as $sw_id => $v) {
        $q .= (int) $sw_id . ',';
    }
    $q = substr ($q, 0, -1) . ') ORDER BY name, size, color';
    $r = mysqli_query ($dbc, $q);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($r) > 0) {

        // Create a table and a form:
        echo '<table border="0" width="90%" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="2" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td align="left" width="20%"><b>Widget</b></td>
            <td align="left" width="15%"><b>Size</b></td>
            <td align="left" width="15%"><b>Color</b></td>
            <td align="right" width="15%"><b>Price</b></td>
            <td align="center" width="10%"><b>Qty</b></td>
            <td align="right" width="15%"><b>Total Price</b></td>
        </tr>
    <form action="cart.php" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="do" value="update" />
    ';

        // Print each item:
        $total = 0; // Total cost of the order.
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($r, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

            // Determine the price:
            $price = (empty($row['price'])) ? $row['default_price'] : $row['price'];

            // Calculate the total and sub-totals:
            $subtotal = $_SESSION['cart'][$row['sw_id']] * $price; 
            $total += $subtotal;
            $subtotal = number_format($subtotal, 2); 

            // Print the row:
            echo <<<EOT
<tr>
    <td align="left">{$row['name']}</td>
    <td align="left">{$row['size']}</td>
    <td align="left">{$row['color']}</td>
    <td align="right">\$$price</td>
    <td align="center"><input type="text" size="3" name="qty[{$row['sw_id']}]" value="{$_SESSION['cart'][$row['sw_id']]}" /></td>
            <td align="right">\$$subtotal</td>
        </tr>\n
EOT;

        } // End of the WHILE loop.

        // Print the footer, close the table, and the form:
        echo '  <tr>
            <td colspan="5" align="right"><b>Total:</b></td>
            <td align="right">$' . number_format ($total, 2) . '</td>
        </tr>   
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6" align="center">Set an item\'s quantity to 0 to remove it from your cart.</td>
        </tr>
        </table><div align="center"><button type="submit" name="submit" value="update">Update Cart</button> &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; 
        <a href="checkout.php"><button type="button" name="checkout" value="Checkout">Checkout</button></a></div>
    </form>';

    } // End of mysqli_num_rows() IF.

} else {
    echo '<p>Your cart is currently empty.</p>';
}

// Include the footer file to complete the template:
include_once ('./includes/footer.html');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A1.
Yes you can start a session this way.  PHP instantiates session keys the same way it instantiates any other variable.

A2.
When you do $_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id]++, you're saying add 1 to the value, not to the key. In other words if $array[0]==5 and you do $array[0]++, you get 6, not $array[1].

Comment: You cannot start a session that way. You can, however, initialize a key in the session that way. The session must be started with `session_start()`.

Comment: @Lucas Oman: a quote from the initial question: "I have a header.html which start with session_start();"

Answer (score 4):

A1. Your session starts when you call `session_start()`. Although a certain variable may not be set in $_SESSION, the session is still initiated.

A2. If you look closely at the code, you'll see that it checks whether `$_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id]` is set yet. If it is, it uses the `++` operator. If not, it initializes it with a value of `1`.

As an aside, you can initialize a variable with `++` in PHP. If the variable or array key is not initialized, PHP assumes it has a starting value of `0`.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `$_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id]++`, you are incrementing the value stored at `$_SESSION['cart'][$sw_id]`, which happens to represent the quantity.

If you were updating the product ID, it would look like `$sw_id++`.

As for the first part of your question, I'm not entirely sure what you're asking. `session_start()` simply "starts" or activates the session for use. Once called, it will populate the `$_SESSION` superglobal with the values stored in the session.